# Checkstyle error on Unix only

Tags: regex, ant, checkstyle

I'm using Ant to run a custom regex based checkstlye for **/*.html files. It's very simple config.
Ant build.xml:

```
<taskdef resource="checkstyletask.properties" classpath="checkstyle-5.5-all.jar"/>
<target name="check">
    <checkstyle config="checks.xml" failOnViolation="false">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="**/*.html"/>
        <formatter type="plain"/>
        <formatter type="xml" toFile="${basedir}/reports/checkstyle-report.xml"/>
    </checkstyle>
</target>
```

checks.xml:

```
<module name="Checker">
    <property name="charset" value="UTF-8"/>
    <module name="RegexpMultiline">
        <property name="format" value="\A.+&lt;table&gt;.+&lt;\/table&gt;.+\Z"/>
    </module>
</module>
```

On Windows 7 64bit:

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.3 compiled on February 26 2012,
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

On CentOS 64bit:

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on May 13 2011,
BUILD FAILED
build.xml:8: Unable to create a Checker: cannot initialize module RegexpMultiline - Unable to instantiate RegexpMultiline
```

Can anyone suggest something?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so simply running ant -v revealed the following:

```
parsing buildfile jar:file:/usr/share/java/ant-1.8.2.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/usr/share/java/ant-1.8.2.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
...
[checkstyle] checkstyle version 4.4
[checkstyle] compiled on Mon December 06 2010, 21:35 GMT
```

So the reason for the failure is not so much to do with the OS, as the version & configuration of the Ant installation.

I think what's happening is that the v4.4 checkstyle is being picked up from

```
/usr/share/java/ant-1.8.2.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml
```

in preference to what is specified in build.xml:

```
<taskdef resource="checkstyletask.properties" classpath="${basedir}/checkstyle/checkstyle-5.5-all.jar"/>
```

---

Update:

I didn't find checkstyle.jar in /usr/share/ant/lib/, but there was one in /usr/share/java/

Not sure how Ant was picking that up, but this is what has finally fixed the issue:

```
yum remove checkstyle4.noarch
```

Now Ant is free to use the .jar from the project!

[Others may find this stackoverflow question relevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825748/how-to-override-ant-task-stored-in-ant-lib-directory)

Comment: checkstyle is a seperate task, I really don't think this has anything to do with /usr/share/java/ant-1.8.2.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml, I would check ANT_HOME/lib for any other checkstyle libs. The version of checkstyle hast to come from a checkstyle lib imho.

Comment: thanks for the link :D I didn't know that the lib dir takes precedence over the classpath attribute/declaration of the taskdef